# Why can't I use two .h file?

Tags: c++, header, namespaces

When I do `#include "George.h"` above `#include "Anna.h"` and then `using namespace Anna;`, it gives me an error 'expected namespace name' and 'unknown type Human, you mean Anna::Human?', but if I type `#include "Anna.h"` above `#include "George.h"`, everything is fine.

So I guess my problem is that I can't include two header files. But why? I'm studying from the udemy course and the teachers' code works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Anna.h"
#include "George.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace George;

int main()
{

    Human human1;
    human1.talk();

    return 0;
}
```

This is Anna.h code:

```
#ifndef HUMAN_H
#define HUMAN_H

namespace Anna
{

class Human
{
    public:

    Human();
    void talk();
    ~Human();

};

}

#endif // HUMAN_H
```

This is George.h code:

```
#ifndef HUMAN_H
#define HUMAN_H

namespace George
{

class Human
{
    public:

    Human();
    void talk();
    ~Human();

};

}

#endif // HUMAN_H
```

Comment: You should show what's in the two headers `Anna.h` and `George.h` (or a small subset of what's in them).

Comment: My money is on your using the same include guards for Anna.h and George.h

Comment: *"So as I guess my problem is that I can't include two header files"* - Don't guess. Post enough for a [mre] and we'll point you at actual the problem.

Comment: You can use multiple headers.  You need those headers to be correct, but you can most certainly use multiple headers.  Your headers should be self-contained, idempotent and minimal.  (Idempotent means you can include it several times in a translation unit or TU without causing trouble.)

Comment: So there is header codes.

Comment: @Bathsheba [wins the prize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584333/why-cant-i-use-two-h-file#comment115955153_65584333)!  Why are you not using header guards `ANNA_H_INCLUDED` and `GEORGE_H_INCLUDED`?  Or any two different names?  With both headers using `#ifndef HUMAN_H` / `#define HUMAN_H` / … / `#endif /* HUMAN_H */`, you can only effectively include one or the other and not both.

Comment: @el1oz The issue was already explained in the comments: "_My money is on your using the same include guards for Anna.h and George.h_", which is exactly, what is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what is header guards :(

Comment: The include guard is the same in both files! @Bathsheba wins!

Comment: @el1oz "_I'm not sure what is header guards_" `#ifndef HUMAN_H #define HUMAN_H ... #endif`.

Comment: I have changed header guard names and it worked. Thank you very much !!

Comment: Note that the solution to your problem was obvious to those more experienced than you as soon as the complete code was posted.  It's very helpful to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
Now you've done that, your problem is easily explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Anna, change `HUMAN_H` to `ANNA_HUMAN_H` and in George change `HUMAN_H` to `GEORGE_HUMAN_H`

I haven't tested this but from the look of the comments (and my own reasoning) it is what's wrong